# Выводит ошибку при полнотекстном запросе

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]При обрабатывании полнотекстного запроса на поиск выдает ошибку

> Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

в таблице все столбцы которые упомянуты в запросе проставлены как FULL TEXT, индексированы и в таблице есть PRIMARY KEY, ключи ENABLE на верняк писал команду `ALTER TABLE 'table name' ENABLE KEYS`

запрос `$sql = "SELECT * FROM`sandoz`WHERE MATCH (AssetType, AssetSubtype, UniqID, Asset_Status, SN, CR_IMEI) AGAINST ('". $_POST["search"] ."')";`

таблица в PHPMyAdmin скрин ниже 
код таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `sandoz` (
  `Inventory_LLC` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `Inventory_DD` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `AssetCategory` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `AssetType` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `AssetSubtype` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Transfer_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Return_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `UniqID` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Asset_Owner` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Owner_Comp` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Owner_Location` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Owner_Status` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Asset_Status` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Asset_Entity` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `SN` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Notes` text COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `CR_IMEI` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Org_Unit` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Position` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Cost` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Any_Val` text COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Pur_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Check_Uncheck` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `Local_Material` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `PO` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `Activated` varchar(255) COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii COLLATE=ascii_bin;

ALTER TABLE `sandoz`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`SN`),
  ADD KEY `SN` (`SN`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `SN_2` (`SN`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `AssetType` (`AssetType`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `AssetSubtype` (`AssetSubtype`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `UniqID` (`UniqID`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `Asset_Status` (`Asset_Status`);
ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `CR_IMEI` (`CR_IMEI`);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Сервер врать не будет. Если он говорит, что нет полнотекстового индекса, список полей которого соответствует списку проверяемых полей в запросе - значит, его нет. *столбцы которые упомянуты в запросе проставлены как FULL TEXT* Нет такого типа, как `FULL TEXT`. Есть тип `TEXT` - но то, что у поля этот тип, вовсе не означает, что полнотекстовый индекс появится сам по себе...

Comment: @Akina вот выше приложил скрин структуры базы

Comment: Не надо фотографий. Покажите DDL таблицы текстом. И собственно сам запрос предъявите.

Comment: @Akina вот добавил запрос и код самой таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запроса MATCH по нескольким полям требуется, чтобы все эти поля были в одном FULLTEXT индексе, а не по индексу на каждое поле. Ошибка и пишет, что не найден индекс, содержащий все поля из запроса

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

> The MATCH() column list must match exactly the column list in some FULLTEXT index definition for the table, unless this MATCH() is IN BOOLEAN MODE on a MyISAM table

Comment: то есть будет ALTER TABLE `sandoz` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `FTK` (`SN, AssetType, AssetSubtype, UniqID, Asset_Status, CR_IMEI`) ??

Comment: да, чтобы все попали в 1 индекс

Comment: спасибо за инфу